# Kafka Topic, Broker, ZooKeeper architecture overview

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have read a bunch of articles regarding Kafka architecture but I'm still brand-new in this and when it came to coding there was some confusion if I get the things correctly.

From what I understand Kafka server, broker and node are synonyms. There can be a few brokers within Kafka cluster. There is a Kafka topic (T1) and it consists of a few partitions (P1, P2..). These partitions can be replicated across the brokers (B1, B2..). B1 can be leader for P1, B2 for P2 and so on. Do we say that there is topic T1 defined for broker or cluster, and if we treat topic as set of partitions can we say 'topic replicas'?

From the official Kafka documentation:

> bootstrap.servers: A list of host/port pairs to use for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster. The client will make use of all servers irrespective of which servers are specified here for bootstrapping—this list only impacts the initial hosts used to discover the full set of servers. This list should be in the form host1:port1,host2:port2,.... Since these servers are just used for the initial connection to discover the full cluster membership (which may change dynamically), this list need not contain the full set of servers (you may want more than one, though, in case a server is down).

So from what I understand, defining host1:port1,host2:port2 says that there are two brokers.

In this case, does ZooKeeper automatically distribute a message to a leader when executing `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list host1:port1,host2:port2 --topic test` ? (I believe somewhere I have read that a producer should read broker id from ZooKeeper, but wouldn't it be unnecessary here?)
Is it equal to publishing using `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --zookeeper host1:z_port1,host2:z_port2 --topic test` ? 
How should I basically understand `bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper host1:z_port1,host2:z_port2`? We have only one zookeeper instance?

Answer (score 0):

> Do we say that there is topic T1 defined for broker or cluster, and if we treat topic as set of partitions can we say 'topic replicas'?

1) Cluster. 2) Partitions are individually replicated across multiple brokers, often more than the replication factor itself. The more proper term would be the "in sync replicas (ISR)"

> does ZooKeeper automatically distribute a message to a leader when executing

Zookeeper does not, no. Your client communicates with a Broker Controller, then receives all brokers in the cluster, which also returns metadata about which broker is the leader for which topic-partitions. The client then individually connects and produces to each leader broker for the calculated partitions

> Is it equal to publishing

Producing*, yes.

> We have only one zookeeper instance?

One Zookeeper **cluster** can manage multiple Kafka clusters via a feature called a `chroot`, the root directory in the Zookeeper znodes that contains information about the managed service.

Also, `kafka-topics` command can now use `--bootstrap-server`, not `--zookeeper`